# Nested resources as_json, sorted, with specific columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 resources: `pages`, `sections`, and `fields` each with `name` and `order` columns.

My goal is to get a JSON representation of all of these resources, ordered by their order columns.

Example output:

```
[
  {"name": "Page 1", "order": 0, "sections":  [
    {"name": "Section 1", "order": 0, "fields": [
      {"name": "Field 1", "order": 0},
      {"name": "Field 2", "order": 1}
    ]},
    {"name": "Section 2", "order": 0, "fields": [
      {"name": "Field 1", "order": 0}
    ]}
  ]},
  {"name": "Page 2", "order": 1, "sections": [
    {"name": "Section 1", "order": 0, "fields": [
      {"name": "Field 1", "order": 0}
    ]}
  ]}
]
```

Note that the above is actual JSON (i.e. after running `to_json`).

For the life of me, I can't figure out a way to do this with ActiveModel.

My most successful attempt is something like this:

```
Page.joins(sections: :fields)
  .as_json(only: [:name, :order], include: {
    sections: {only: [:name, :order], include: {
      fields: {only: [:prototype_id, :order]}
    }}
  })
```

This allows me to select the name and order, but then I have to recursively sort every array.

If I try to let ActiveModel do the sorting, I have to select the specific columns in SQL, which requires me to join, which requires a distinct, which makes the JSON nesting very tricky...

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions to implement the **Order** on AR:

**Solution #1:**
You can order the model and its' associations using **.order** as below:

```
Page.joins(sections: :fields).order("pages.order, sections.order, fields.order")
```

**Reference:**
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

**Solution #2:**
Add sorting to **default scope** as below:

```
class Page 
  default_scope { order(order: :asc) }
end

class Section 
  default_scope { order(order: :asc) }
end

class Field 
  default_scope { order(order: :asc) }
end
```

**Reference:**
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class